# iOS - Integrating third party library and setting dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, dependencies

So, we need to integrate a library in our application, which is gonna be developed by another organization. This library will wrap some other, external, libs and export them to our app + an small sdk to handle a specific flow. At the end, this sdk is going to make some network calls.

The developers of the library are asking us to provide dependencies if any and how to distribute the lib.

We will agree on cocoapods, minimum sdks, and i think its wise to tell them to use the same swift version we are using as well as the same Alamofire version.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cocoa pods for the integration of the plugins, the resolving of the dependencies will be managed by cocoa pods. In the .podspec file of the plugin, you can define dependencies of the plugin itself. ([podspec documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html))
If you are currently developing the plugin you might hit some incompatibilities, but if you have contact to the developers of the plugin, those should be solvable.